# I don't understand output of My program, Explain please

Tags: java, methods, subclass, superclass, inherited

I have 4 class and 1 interface
In **interface** have 2 abstract methods (myMethod(int k) and getV())

```
public interface MyInterface
{ public abstract void myMethod(int k);
 public abstract int getV();
}
```

In **MySuperClass** that implements MyInterface

```
public class MySuperClass implements MyInterface
{ private int v;
 public MySuperClass() { this(2); }
 public MySuperClass(int vValue) { v = vValue; }
 public void myMethod(int k) { v += k; }
 public void myMethod() { v--; }
 public int getV() { return v; }
 public String toString() { return Integer.toString(v); }
}
```

In **MySubClass** that extends MySuperClass

```
public class MySubClass extends MySuperClass
{ private int v;
 public MySubClass() { this(1); }
 public MySubClass(int vValue) { v = vValue; }
 public void myMethod(int k) { myMethod(); super.myMethod(k); }
 public int getV() { return v; }
 public String toString() { return super.toString() + " " + Integer.toString(v); }
}
```

**MyOtherClass** implements MyInterface

```
public class MyOtherClass implements MyInterface
{ private int v;
 public MyOtherClass() { this(0); }
 public MyOtherClass(int vValue) { v = vValue; }
 public void myMethod(int k) { v-= k; }
 public void myMethod() { v++; }
 public int getV() { return v; }
 public String toString() { return Integer.toString(v); }
}
```

In the **main** class

```
public class MyMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyInterface[] mif
                = {new MySuperClass(), new MyOtherClass(), new MySubClass()};

        mif[mif[2].getV()].myMethod(1);
        for (int i = 0; i < mif.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(mif[i]);
        }
        mif[mif[0].getV()].myMethod(2);
        for (int i = 0; i < mif.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(mif[i]);
        }}}
```

output
2
-1
2 1
2
-1
3 1

I don't understand line 6 is *3 1*, why not *4 0*

I think output is 4 0 because
mif[mif[0].getV()].myMethod(2); => mif[2].myMethod(2); => MySubClass.myMethod(2);
and `public void myMethod(int k) {myMethod(); super.myMethod(k); }`
I think 'myMethod()' change 'v' as 1 so v = 0
and super.myMethod(k) change 'v' as 2 so v = 4

Comment: No offense but it looks like it's made to be a mess on purpose

Comment: yes,I don't understand the output is 3 1 why not 4 0

Comment: can you explain why you think the output is supposed to be '4 0'?  describe the steps that the code executes.

Comment: I added a description in post

Comment: I think you haven't copied the outputs correctly. You might have got 2, 1, 2 -1, 3, -1, 3 -1. Please check again.

Comment: I checked in netBeans

Comment: @micky Please check the results again, because I've edited my answer, but the first number in line 6 will ALWAYS be the value in line 4, without any modification.

Comment: @micky Please copy the result directly from the program to the question, because there is no way the answers you have currently shown are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you've understood lines 1 - 3.

At this point, `MySuperClass.v` = 2, `MySubClass.v` = 1, `MyOtherClass.v` = -1

I'm gonna refer to them as Super, Sub and Other.

Now, `mif[0].getV()` returns 2. Therefore, mif[2].myMethod(2) calls MySubClass.myMethod(2), which in turn calls myMethod() and Super.myMethod(2)

Now, myMethod() the value of **Super.v** to 1, and Super.myMethod(2) changes the value of Super.v from 1 to 3

At this point, Super.v = 3, Sub.v = 1, Other.v = -1

So, line 4 gives `Super.v` = `3`,
Line 5 gives `Other.v` = `-1`,
Line 6 gives `Super.v Sub.v` = `3 1`

You might have noticed that the outputs I've explained are different from the current post, and that's because I'm 100% sure OP has copied the outputs into his question wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I really don't understand why the value of myMethod()  is super.v not sub.v (sorry for my question is not obvious and my gramma)

Comment: @micky MySubClass inherits both the methods and the variables from MySuperClass. This means that MySubClass.myMethod(2) calls Super.myMethod() and Super.myMethod(2) one after the other, so the value of Super.v is changed from 2 to -1, then from -1 to 3

Comment: @micky If your question has been answered satisfactorily, please mark this answer as accepted, and upvote it so that others may also be able to refer to this question :)